# is this a right way to compute the integral?

Tags: integration

I have for  positive integers $m$ and $n$  $$ g(t)= \int_{0}^{1-t} t^{m-1}\left[(u+t)^{m}-u^{m}\right]^{n-2}(u+t)^{m-1} d u $$

I need to calculate $ I=\int_0^1tg(t)dt$.Taking $g(t)$ as the first function and integrating by parts ,I get: $$ I=g(t)t^2/2]_{t=0}^1-\int_0^1 g'(t) \frac{t^2}{2}=\int_0^1t^{2}(1-t)^{m-1}\left[1-(1-t)^m\right]^{n-2} d t$$, where
$$ g'(t)=  t^{m-1}\left[(u+t)^{m}-u^{m}\right]^{n-2}(u+t)^{m-1}]_{u=1-t}.\frac{d}{dt}(1-t)-0 $$
I just want want to confirm if my calculations are all correct.Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What are the limitation for $m$ and $n$? Please also clarify why the power $(n-2)$ disappeared from the final expression - is it the typo?

Comment: @Svyatoslav lots of thanks for pointing out the typo. I made the correction.m and n are positive  integers

Comment: are they positive? any limitations?

Comment: they are positive integers

Comment: I'm afraid your integration by part is not correct. Do I understand correctly that you have to integrate both $u$ and $t$ (do you have a double integral $\int\int du dt$) ? the task is not fully clear...

Comment: @Svyatoslav I have made an edit .Does it make sense now ?I  have calculated the derivative of g using differentiation under integral sign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123701/discussion-between-svyatoslav-and-sajjad-veeri).